# Input type=color event on color picker window closed

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom-events

Using neat html5 feature color input:

```
<input type="color" ...
```

Google Chrome browser provides a nice little color picker window for it. Is any particular event emitted when color picker popup window is closed? Both `input`  and `change` fire on any color selection and `submit` does not fire until a form is submitted.

**[UPDATE]**

As of now (December 10th 2016) color picker `change` event still fires every time `input` event does. So what I ended up doing is to use `$('#myPicker').focus()` event since after each color picker little window close focus does return to the input element. As was suggested in the comments.

Comment: Does the focus leave the element?

Comment: The change event fires when the color actually changes, and that happens when the popup closes, what more could you want ?

Comment: adeneo, I'm using Google Chrome 35.0.1916.114 and `change` is fired on every interaction with color picker window i.e. moving hue and color selectors.

Comment: epascarello, yes, focus leaves the element and returns on window close.

Comment: The change event is the right event for this. In case chrome does fire a change event this is a spec violation. The change event should only be dispatched on a commit action. You should file a bug! see also: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155747